# Need help changing where iptables logs to

Tags: ubuntu, logging, iptables

I'm writing a program that needs to read in and look at the iptables log file.  I know how to write rules for iptables and to make it log, but by default it logs to kernel.log.  Is there a way to make it's own log file?  Sorry if it's a stupid question, huge linux noob here.

Comment: Modify the syslog configuration.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/force-iptables-to-log-messages-to-a-different-log-file.html